# Sql where with one negative and two positives

Tags: mysql, sql

In the settings page the user can change the name and mail. I want to make a select to check that the user does not choose a name or mail that already exists. I could come with that, it works well but only for the name:

```
SELECT name 
FROM user 
WHERE NOT id = :id
AND name = :name
```

I tried that for the name and password and it does not make the right selection:

```
SELECT name, mail 
FROM user 
WHERE NOT id = :id
AND name = :name OR mail = :mail
```

How to select the name and mail that is not a specific id (in this case the id of the user of the session)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need parentheses:

```
WHERE NOT id = :id AND
      ( name = :name OR mail = :mail )
```